# цикл for of не работает

Tags: javascript

Существует массив, элементы которого имеют тип string, примеры элементов: "1", "2" и т.д. Я хочу изменить тип элементов на number. Задача пустяковая, перебрать массив циклом, например, **for** и воспользоваться **Number()**.
мой код (использую цикл **for of**):

```
"use strict";

let globNumb = "1234567";
let globArr = globNumb.split('');//получаю массив, элементы которого имеют тип string

for (let globElem of globArr ) {
  if( (typeof globElem) == "string" ) {
    globElem = Number(globElem);
  }
}
```

Теперь, если проверить переменную **globArr**, то видно, что элементы массива **globArr** по-прежнему имеют тип string.
Но вот если вместо **for of** воспользоваться несколько другим циклом:

```
for (let i = 0; i < globArr.length; i++) {
  if ( (typeof globArr[i]) == "string" ) {
    globArr[i] = Number(globArr[i]);
  }
}
```

то все работает, а именно, элементы массива **globArr** имеют тип **number**, что мне и нужно.
**Вопрос:** почему с данной задачей не справляется цикл **for of**? Или я делаю что-то неправильно?

Comment: Потому что `globElem` есть _копия_ элемента из массива `globArr`. Её изменение не изменяет элементы массива `globArr`.

Comment: @wololo, если это так, то существует ли способ изменить элемент массива **globArr**, используя **for of**?

Comment: А это хороший вопрос. Судя по всему нельзя. Если я не прав, кто-нибудь наверняка покажет способ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы перезаписать элемент массива, вам необходимо знать его индекс, иначе не получится.

Цикл `for...of` производит итерацию массива по значениям элементов, но не предоставляет индексы. То есть, в нём можно получить значения элементов, но не перезаписать элементы.

Та же самая итерация происходит, если итерировать не сам массив, а итератор, возвращаемый [`Array.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values).

Если вы хотите использовать именно `for...of`, а не функции, предоставляющие индексы (вроде [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), вам нужно выбрать другой вид итератора, в котором есть индексы.

У вас есть такие два варианта.

1. Использовать [`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys):

```js
"use strict";

const globNumb = "1234567";
const globArr = globNumb.split('');

for (const index of globArr.keys()) {
  if (typeof globArr[index] === 'string') {
    globArr[index] = Number(globArr[index]);
  }
}

console.log(globArr);
```

2. Использовать [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), что немного упростит запись:

```js
"use strict";

const globNumb = "1234567";
const globArr = globNumb.split('');

for (const [index, value] of globArr.entries()) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    globArr[index] = Number(value);
  }
}

console.log(globArr);
```

Comment: благодарю. Пожалуй, это то, что я искал. Насколько я понял из написанного вами, в данном примере **итератор** - это объект, возвращаемый универсальными методами keys(), values(), entries()?

Comment: Да. Если не ошибаюсь, итератор .values() также работает под капотом, если перебирать массив в цикле for... of, или использовать оператор спред (...), или производить деконструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

Тут 2 варианта.

Искать элемент в исходном массиве, и менять его значение:

```
let globNumb = "1234567";
let globArr = globNumb.split('');//получаю массив, элементы которого имеют тип string

for (let globElem of globArr ) {
  if( (typeof globElem) == "string" ) {
    let index = globArr.indexOf(globElem);
    globArr[index] = Number(globElem);
  }
}
```

Или использовать конструкцию **for in**:

```
let globNumb = "1234567";
let globArr = globNumb.split('');//получаю массив, элементы которого имеют тип string

for (let index in globArr) {
  if( (typeof globArr[index]) == "string" ) {
    globArr[index] = Number(globArr[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. По поводу первого варианта - полезная для меня информация. По поводу ** for in**: Насколько мне известно, не следует использовать цикл for..in для массивов. Вот здесь про это написано: https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Comment: @freestyle_HD, способ с `indexOf` так-то тоже не очень хорош. `indexOf` последовательно перебирает элементы массива, пока не наткнётся на равный искомому. Это автоматически делает первый алгоритм имеющим квадратичную сложность.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы действительно хотите преобразовать некие значения в массиве, то лучше это сделать через map:

```
// const newGlobArr = globArr.map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? +value : value);

const newGlobArr = globArr.map((value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return Number(value);
  }

  return value;
});
```

Comment: но это же создаст новый массив, а не изменит существующий